# DAX Calculate Sum of sales per productid filter by productid ( NOT IN TOP 20 )

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am fairly new to PowerBI DAX and I want to filter out the top 20 product ids in a measure.

I came up with this formula but it does not seem to be working and I was hoping to get some help here.

```
$ Amount Parcel = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Data[$ Amount Parcel]),
        FILTER (Data, NOT (Data[idProduct], SUM(Data[NetSales])) IN TOPN(20, SUMMARIZE(Data, Data[idProduct], "NetSales", SUM(Data[NetSales]))))
  )
```

I want to show sales per PID for all products except for our 20 best sellers.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest an easier approach adding a dimension column.

First of all, you need to have Product dimension table separated from Sales fact table. Make sure to create one-to-many relationship between Product and Sales with "Single" cross filter direction.

[image]

Then you can create a calculated column on Product table, which can be used to filter out top selling products.

```
Sales Rank = RANKX('Product', CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[SalesAmount])))
```

Now drag and drop Sales Rank field into the Filters pane of your visualization, and set the filter condition so that top selling products will not be shown.

[image]